# Проверка cтрок вида "1,2,3;45,25,65;4,2,78" помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярку проверяющую строку вида: "1,2,3;45,25,65;4,2,78" .
Поясненения к строке:

1. Количество чисел до точки запятой, разделенных запятыми ("1,2,3")  постоянно везде;
2. Конец строки не заканчивается знаком -  ";"

Мой вариант регулярки: r"((\d+,){n-1}\d+;)*((\d+,){n-1}\d+)" где n - это количество чисел разделенных запятыми. Есть ли способ написать то же самое, только короче и элегантнее.

Строки для тестирования:

```
1,2,3;45,25,65;4,2,78
1,5,9;8,9,55
1,2;3,4;5,9;               # no match (два числа в группе, вместо трех)
1,2;3,4;5,9                # no match (два числа в группе, вместо трех) 
1,5,8
1,2,3;                     # no match (";" в конце строки)
```

Comment: вы можете привести несколько (5-7) строк для тестирования? Вас интересует проверка на наличие подстроки или парсинг нужных элементов из строки или же проверка всей строки целиком?

Comment: Меня интересует проверка строки целиком.
Примеры строк: 
- "1,2;3,4;5,9"
- "1,5,9;8,9,55"
- "1,5,8" - и так далее

Comment: `^((\d+,){n-1}\d+(;|$))*`

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста момент с ;.

Comment: Нет, подумал - не упрощает, всё равно тестирование на конец строки надо оставлять. Коммент удалил.

Comment: Регулярное выражение матчит и строку вида "1,2;3,4;5,9;", хотя не должно. То есть в конце строки не должно быть точки запятой

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян, так как на счет примеров строк для тестирования [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/976569/edit)? ;)

Comment: Строки для тестирования:
"1,2;3,4;5,9" 
- "1,5,9;8,9,55"
 - "1,5,8"

Comment: Мда, не силён... но у меня короче всего получается паттерн именно с добавлением `;` в хвост проверяемой строки. Т.е. (сори, синтаксис питона не знаю) что-то типа `re.match('^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', my_string + ';')`

Comment: @Akina, отличная идея проверять `string + ';'` ! Может оформите как ответ? Вместо Python кода вполне подойдет "test case" на regex101.com

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем в конец строки точку с запятой, после чего проверяем шаблоном `r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$'`.

Вот этот код правильно работает при проверке на https://pyfiddle.io/ (ссылку не дам - лень регистрироваться)

```
import re
print(re.match(r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', '1,2,3;4,5,6'       + ';'))
print(re.match(r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', '1,2,3;4,5,6;'      + ';'))
print(re.match(r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', '1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9' + ';'))
print(re.match(r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', '1,2,3'             + ';'))
print(re.match(r'^((\d+,){2}\d+;)*$', '1,2;3,4;5,6'       + ';'))
```

Строки 2 и 5 - не проходят проверку, остальные проходят.

Comment: А можно правее print в комментах указать результат match? :) так нагляднее будет )

Comment: Можно [оформить в виде функции](https://repl.it/repls/AnxiousDependentSpellchecker)

Answer (score 0):

`(1,2,3;)([0-9]+,){2}([0-9]+;)([0-9]+,){2}([0-9]+)$`
как вариант.

Comment: автор вопроса просил элегантнее чем у него ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Мой вариант регулярки: `r"((\d+,){n-1}\d+;)*((\d+,){n-1}\d+)"` где `n` - это количество чисел разделенных запятыми. Есть ли способ написать то же самое, только короче и элегантнее.

```
r"^(?=.*[^;]$)((\d+,){n-1}\d+(;|$))+$"
```

А вот сделать автоматический подсчёт чисел, разделённых запятыми, вроде не получится.